# Importing data into an excel table but excluding some data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, import

I wrote some code that imports a couple of columns from another excel workbook, and it works ok. But I realized that a lot of the data should be excluded. The way the VBA code works is that it finds the header cell in the target workbook for each of the 4 columns I want to import, and then copies all data below those cells into the appropirate column in my target table. As it turns out the 4th column "Months" has a lot of data with "0" in it. I want to exclude all of the rows that have a 0 in it. Not sure what is the best way to accomplis this. I've included the relevant portion of the code below and would appreciate any help and/or ideas on how to best accomplish this. I'm not sure how best to structure the loop without completly rewriting my code. Maybe I have to.

```
   

    Sub ImportBalanceSheet_Click()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim tblTarget As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim frm As DepreciationForm
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' Set reference to the target worksheet and table
    Set wsTarget = ActiveSheet
    Set tblTarget = wsTarget.ListObjects("tblBalanceSheet")
    
    If tblTarget Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "named tblBalanceSheet is not found in current tab"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If table is empty, add a row to prevent a run-time error from occuring when we copy new data to the table
    If tblTarget.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        tblTarget.ListRows.Add
    End If
    
    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    
    If fName = False Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Open source workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    
    ' Create and populate the form
    Set frm = DepreciationForm
    For Each ws In wbSource.Sheets
        frm.cBoxTab.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws
    
    ' Show the form
    frm.Show vbModal
    
    ' Get the selected sheet
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(frm.cBoxTab.Value)
    
    ' Clear the Combo Box and close the form
    frm.cBoxTab.Clear
    frm.Hide
    
    ' Find name, class, and location columns by their headers
    Dim nameColumn As Range
    Dim classColumn As Range
    Dim locationColumn As Range
    Dim monthsColumn As Range
    
    
    For Each rng In wsSource.UsedRange
        If rng.Value = "Asset Description" Then
            Set nameColumn = rng
        ElseIf rng.Value = "Asset Class" Then
            Set classColumn = rng
        ElseIf rng.Value = "Functional Location Name" Then
            Set locationColumn = rng
        ElseIf rng.Value = "Remaining Months of Depreciation" Then
            Set monthsColumn = rng
        End If
    Next rng
    
    If nameColumn Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Asset Name column not found in selected tab"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If classColumn Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Asset Class column not found in selected tab"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If locationColumn Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Asset Location column not found in selected tab"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If monthsColumn Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Asset Remaing Depreciation column not found in selected tab"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy Name data to target table
    wsSource.Range(nameColumn.Offset(1, 0), nameColumn.End(xlDown)).Copy
    tblTarget.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Copy Location data to target table
    wsSource.Range(locationColumn.Offset(1, 0), locationColumn.End(xlDown)).Copy
    tblTarget.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Copy Class data to target table
    wsSource.Range(classColumn.Offset(1, 0), classColumn.End(xlDown)).Copy
    tblTarget.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Copy Remaing Months of Depreciation data to target table
    wsSource.Range(monthsColumn.Offset(1, 0), monthsColumn.End(xlDown)).Copy
    tblTarget.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Close source workbook
    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
    Dim filterRange As Range  
    Dim monthrange As Range

    Set monthrange = wsSource.Range(monthsColumn.Offset(1, 0), monthsColumn.End(xlDown))

   ' Apply filter to exclude values "0"
    monthrange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
    
    ' Set the filtered range (excluding the header row)
    Set filterRange = monthrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' Copy filtered values to target range
    filterRange.Copy
    tblTarget.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Clear the filter
    wsSource.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: Is the data you want to copy organized in a Table with a known name or is it in a range with headers? From what you described it seems that the headers are on the same line, are they always in the same order or not? if so, which one is the first? I ask this because the code may work but it can be improved

Comment: The source data is not organized in a table, though a filter is already applied to the headers. The header names don’t change but can end up in different order and don’t necessarily start on the same row. The source file is essentially an report output file and depending on what the user selects as their desired output the structure can be different the only static items are the name of the headers I would want to import.

Comment: I would like to post an answer but I need to be absolutely sure what exactly you want. The data to be copied is scattered in columns and even starts from different lines. The beginning of the data is determined by the position of the header. But all the data is related to each other in a way that if I filter the "Months" column then I will copy from all the other columns the corresponding rows left (after filtering) in the "Months" column. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: That is correct. All the data is related to each other. If I filter the months column to exclude 0, the entire row should be filtered out. The position of the header row could conceivable change because the user who runs the report may select certain option in the reporting software that puts some summary data above the header row. I’m not interested in that summary data, but it could occupy  more or less rows. They also may chose to report only certain headers and could conceivably change the order the headers are arranged as their software allows them to do so.

Comment: The only thing I’m guaranteed is that the header rows I’m importing will be part of the source report.

Comment: @jmt78 edited,see if it works now

Answer (score 0):

It was easier for me to filter the results in the target table instead of the source worksheet. thanks k1dr0ck for giving me the idea. I used the following code that seems to work fine. If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve the code, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
    ' Apply filter to "MO. REMAIN" to exclude 0
    Dim monthDepCol As Integer
    monthDepCol = tblTarget.ListColumns("MO. REMAIN").Index
    tblTarget.Range.AutoFilter Field:=monthDepCol, Criteria1:="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the problem has complexity I broke it into four smaller ones so that they can be reused in similar cases. The rationale is as follows: 1) I call CopyFromColumsInTable in which I pass in parameters all the information to complete the process. Here there is some convention as to how you will write the parameters, because you can give via ParamArray headCaptionAndDestinationCol() As Variant as many headers as you want, beside the name of each caption you give the number of the column to which it will be copied. The FIRST one you write will be the one that will set the filtering criteria. 2) Then I find the addresses of all the headers (here there will be a problem if there are many cells with the same header) 3) Then I filter the column with the disputed header and get in a Range the filtered cells. 4) I prepare the copy table (I add as many lines as needed) 5) Calculating based on the addresses of the headers their relative positions in relation to the header of the column I filtered, I copy in a loop the other areas without needing any more filtering but only relative displacement of the original area I found. Of course there are a lot of small details and you can ask me if you don't understand something.

```
Sub copyInitiator()
   'in my example i will copy some data of the of a sheet
   'in a table in the same sheet. The source and destination are
   'parameters so you can modify as needed
   
   'COPY IN TABLE "tblBalanceSheet" the data of Sheet Me, with criteria for first
   'column ("Remaining Months of Depreciation") to be "<>0". Look for the data
   'below the cells with values .... in sheet Me and copy that data in "tblBalanceSheet" table
   ' at listcolumn with index ....
   ' data of "Remaining Months of Depreciation" in column 4 of "tblBalanceSheet"
   ' data of "Asset Description" in column 1 of "tblBalanceSheet" ....
   
   Call CopyFromColumsInTable(Me.ListObjects("tblBalanceSheet"), Me, "<>0", _
                              "Remaining Months of Depreciation", 4, _
                              "Asset Description", 1, _
                              "Asset Class", 2, _
                              "Functional Location Name", 3)
End Sub


'*********************************************************************************************
' targetTable> table to copy at its columns the data that will find in srcWSheet
' srcWSheet> the Sheet with the data to retrieve
' fistHeaderCriteria> simple filtering criteria for the first column (first in ParamArray)
' headCaptionAndDestinationCol> An array with pairs of values as: the header Caption
'   (the value of a cell anywhere in srcWSheet) in srcWSheet and the column at targetTable to copy the data.
'   We can pass as many pairs as needed. eg: "Customer", 4, "Date of birth", 1, ....
'*********************************************************************************************
Public Function CopyFromColumsInTable(targetTable As ListObject, _
                                       srcWSheet As Worksheet, _
                                       firstHeaderCriteria As String, _
                                       ParamArray headCaptionAndDestinationCol() As Variant) As Integer
                                       
   Dim r As Range, tmpr As Range, tmp0 As Range, hdAddrress() As String, hdVal() As String, colInTargetTable() As Long
   Dim msg As String, half As Long, found As Long, c As Long, ub As Long, rowDif As Long, colDif As Long
   
   ' base of ParamArray is 0
   ub = UBound(headCaptionAndDestinationCol)
   If ub Mod 2 = 0 Then
      MsgBox ("Incorrect 'headCaptionAndDestinationCol' parameters")
      Exit Function
   End If
   half = ub \ 2
   
   ReDim hdVal(0 To half)
   ReDim hdAddrress(0 To half)
   ReDim colInTargetTable(0 To half)
   
   'from ParamArray headCaptionAndDestinationCol() we make two other arrays, one with header names and another
   'with the position (column index) to copy the data in target table
   For c = 0 To half
      hdVal(c) = headCaptionAndDestinationCol(c * 2)
      colInTargetTable(c) = headCaptionAndDestinationCol(((c + 1) * 2) - 1)
   Next
   
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lerror
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   
   'the findHeaders function return the number of founded headers AND the
   'cells (as addresses) in array hdAddrress()
   found = findHeaders(srcWSheet, hdAddrress, hdVal)
   
   'found all captions?
   If found < half + 1 Then
      For c = 0 To half
         If hdAddrress(c) = vbNullString Then
            msg = msg & hdVal(c) & vbCrLf
         End If
      Next
      If (msg <> "") Then
         MsgBox ("HEADERS NOT FOUND:" & vbCrLf & msg)
         Exit Function
      End If
   End If
   'all captions founded
   
   'range of first caption
   Set tmp0 = srcWSheet.Range(hdAddrress(0))
   
   'getVisibleRangeOfColumn returns the visible cells in captions column (after the caption)
   'after setting the filter in variable firstHeaderCriteria
   Set r = getVisibleRangeOfColumn(tmp0, firstHeaderCriteria)
   
   'prepare the target table
   If Not targetTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
      targetTable.DataBodyRange.Delete
   End If
   'add lines to table
   For c = 1 To r.CountLarge
      targetTable.ListRows.Add
   Next
   
   'copy the filered data (in r) in column  colInTargetTable(0) as readed from ParamArray
   Call copyFilterdAt(r, targetTable.ListColumns(colInTargetTable(0)).DataBodyRange(1))
   
   'copy all other data columns calculating their relative position from the position
   'of the Caption column we set criteria and get the result in variable r
   For c = 1 To half
      Set tmpr = srcWSheet.Range(hdAddrress(c))
      Call copyFilterdAt(r.Offset(tmpr.Row - tmp0.Row, tmpr.Column - tmp0.Column), _
                           targetTable.ListColumns(colInTargetTable(c)).DataBodyRange(1))
   Next
   Application.CutCopyMode = 0
Lerror:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox (Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number: " & Err.Number) '"ERROR IN Worksheet_Change of sheet " & Me.Name & vbCrLf &
   End If
End Function


'******************************************************************
' ws> Sheet to scan for Header/Caption values
' hdAddrress> a Variable array to fill with the addresses of found Headers (return to caller)
' hdrVal> a Variable array with Header values to find in the sheet ws
' return the number of found headers (and the filled hdAddrress)
'******************************************************************
Function findHeaders(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef hdAddrress As Variant, hdrVal As Variant) As Long
   Dim rng As Range, c As Long, ub As Long, found As Long
   Dim hdrs() As Range

   ub = UBound(hdrVal)
   
   For Each rng In ws.UsedRange
      For c = 0 To ub
         If rng.value = hdrVal(c) Then
            hdAddrress(c) = rng.Address
            findHeaders = findHeaders + 1
            'if found all STOP scanning cells
            If (findHeaders = ub + 1) Then Exit Function
         End If
      Next
   Next
End Function


'***************************************************************
' head> a cell in a sheet
' criteria> criteria for filtering the head column
' Returns> the visible data of the column below the head as range
'***************************************************************
Public Function getVisibleRangeOfColumn(head As Range, criteria As String) As Range
   Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject
   If head Is Nothing Then Exit Function
   With head
      Set ws = .Worksheet
      If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
         ws.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
      
      'we have to resize (two columns) to be sure that the filter begins at range => head
      .Resize(1, 2).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criteria
      Set getVisibleRangeOfColumn = ws.Range(.Offset(1), .Offset(ws.Rows.CountLarge - .Row).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      .AutoFilter
   End With
End Function

'******************************************************************
' srcRng> a range with NO CONTINOUS data from filtering a column
' destCell> a destination range to copy all parts of srcRng (default copy the values, but can copy the cells)
' Optional copyValues> boolean indicator for copying Values or Cells (default => values)
'******************************************************************
Public Sub copyFilterdAt(ByRef srcRng As Range, destCell As Range, Optional copyValues As Boolean = True)
   Dim ar As Range
   For Each ar In srcRng.Areas
      With ar
         If copyValues Then
            .Copy
            Call destCell.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
         Else
            Call .Copy(destCell.Resize(.Rows.CountLarge, .Columns.CountLarge))
         End If
         Set destCell = destCell.Offset(.Rows.CountLarge, 0)
      End With
   Next
End Sub
```

[image]

The picture is exactly my example (all in the same sheet source and desination)

Comment: A variation to give more flexibility is to be able with one more parameter to choose whether the data will be appended to the existing table entries.